# Указать рандомное имя для файла

Tags: java

Учусь писать автотесты на java. В данном случае я хочу вводить данные в поля регистрации, намеренно ошибаюсь и делаю скриншот ошибки с сайта. Когда я регистрирую 1 человека - все ок. Но сейчас, я использую @DataProvider для регистрации нескольких пользователей. И теперь, каждый раз скриншот перезаписывает старый. Вопрос собственно в том, как сделать имя файла рандомным или привязанным к времени.
Для того, чтобы сделать скрин использую такой вариант кода

```
    TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
    File scrFile = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    File desFile = new File( "./Screenshot/.png");
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile,desFile);
```

Comment: посмотрите на `File.createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix, File directory)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Использовать UUID для генерации случайного имени.

```
    String filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    File file = new File("./Screenshot/" + filename + ".png");
```

2. Проверить существует ли файл с таким именем в директории.

```
    if (file.exists());
```

3. Если файл существует, повторить шаг 1 пока не сгенерируется уникальное имя.

Альтернативный вариант, использовать

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

по аналогичной схеме с проверкой существования файла.